# React native packager "Requesting bundle" stuck

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, npm, watchman

I running my app in iOS simulator as well as device iPhone6s plus. My react native app not loading in device. My package manager stuck on "Requesting bundle". See in screenshot,[image]

Interesting thing is my app properly load if run it in debug mode(Using chrome) but its very slow interaction. In debug mode web service callback get after so longer time. 
I try command `$ watchman watch-del-all` but not worked for me.
I'm using react-native 0.35.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason for using 0.35? I had a somewhat similar problem but went away when I updated to react-native@0.43.3

Comment: @Raymond hi thanks for your reply. I may be up-gradation of react native resolve my problem but i can't do this. I'm using so many other node modules (this code going on since 1+ year) and those modules are dependent on react native 0.35. All versions of app i fixed.